# VMware vFabric Data Director

Tags: vmware

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/cloud-alternatives-to-microsoft-sql-server/

I liked the idea of VMware vFabric Data Director so I can host data in own cloud / data centre. It seems this product is now end of life.

Do you know of any similar products still available in the market? I was looking for ways of reducing our licencing overhead with the costs of SQL server increasing, I also like the concept of database as a service taking away DBA bottlenecks in projects.

Comment: https://www.compose.io/

Answer (score 1):

Folks I see going in this direction tend to go with Amazon RDS or Microsoft Azure SQL DB. If you’re interested in reducing DBA costs, you’re also usually interested in reducing sysadmin and hardware costs, too.